# count items by uniq name divide by item number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Basicly i have chart as below;

What i want to do is the divide uniq items by number column and get a sum.
For instance;

```
Apple, Banana             | 8
Banana                    | 4
Cheese, Apple, Banana     | 6
```

So at first column i have 'Apple, Banana' and total number is 8. So i am dividing 8 to number of items 2(apple+banana) and adding 4 to Apple and 4 to Banana.

At 'Cheese,Apple,Banana' that i am dividing 6 to number of items which is 3 and adding 2 to Cheese, 2 to Apple and 2 to Banana, and so on...

```
Total
Apple  | 10
Banana | 10
Cheese | 2
```

Is there any way to do so in Excel ?

Comment: in your totals Apple should only be 6 as it is in only the first and the last.

Comment: that's correct ! apple should be 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this SUMPRODUCT to iterate, count and divide.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((LEN($A$1:$A$3 & ",")-(LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A$1:$A$3 & ",",A6&",",""))))/LEN(A6&","))*($B$1:$B$3/(LEN($A$1:$A$3)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A$1:$A$3,",",""))+1)))
```

[image]